Is it possible to read a file in parallel by extending this function?
I developed this function in C to read a file consisting of one word per line, like a standard wordlist.
The function has already been optimized to a reasonable extent, but I would like to know if there is a way to parallelize the file reading process using OpenMP. I have tried various approaches, but I couldn’t find a working solution.
The idea I had was to divide the task among threads so that each thread uses a private array to store the words it reads, and then later merge these words into the output array (used in the main function) in parallel. However, I wasn’t able to implement this approach successfully.
Is there a possible solution to my problem?
Here's the code of the function:
    int file_read(const char *filename, unsigned char (*output)[MAX_WORD_LENGTH]) {
            int fd = open(filename , O_RDONLY);
            if ( fd < 0 ){
                printf("Errore nella lettura del file\n");
                perror("fd < 0");
                exit(1);
            }
            // dimensione  file in byte
            off_t file_size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
            lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

            // Mappiamo il file in memoria
            char *file_data = (char *) mmap(NULL, file_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
            //mmap funzione che permette di mappare in memoria il file
            //NULL significa che decide l'os dove metterlo
            //file_size quanto è grande, calcolato prima con lseek
            //PROT_READ dice che il file è solo in lettura
            //MAP_PRIVATE privata al processo, alternativamente MAP_SHARED
            //fd file descriptor
            //0 dove iniziare a leggere il file, 0 = inizio
            if (file_data == MAP_FAILED) {
                perror("Errore nella mappatura del file");
                close(fd);
                exit(1);
            }

            close(fd);

            int num_words = 0;
            int i=0, temp_len=0;
            char tempChar;
            while ( i < file_size && num_words < MAX_WORDS ){
                tempChar = file_data[i];
                if(tempChar=='\n'){
                    if(temp_len <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH){
                        if(temp_len > 0){
                            output[num_words][temp_len]='\0';
                            temp_len = 0;
                            num_words++;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("Parola troppo grande");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }
                else if(tempChar!='\r'){
                    output[num_words][temp_len++]=tempChar;
                }
                i++;
            }

            //rilascio la memoria su cui era inserito il file
            munmap(file_data, file_size);

            return num_words;

        }

P.S. This code is designed to read a large amount of data, such as one million words and the max lenght of a word is 56 in my case.
Thanks.

Disk access is more or less serial. What's worse is that unless every single line is the exact same length no process or thread will know where to start or stop reading.

Bottom line: read the whole file - or as much as you have room for - into a buffer, then you can parallelize the processing you do on the buffer.

I don't think its easy to create a parallel application for counting words within a buffer, because you'd have to know beforehand where spaces are placed, so you can equally divide the buffer into minor slices. Imagine that you have a file with the following string abc de fgh, then you slice it in two halves: abc d and e fgh. How each thread knows that d and e are part of the same word? They don't. That's the problem.

@ric, Bug: output[num_words][temp_len]='\0'; can attempt output[num_words][MAX_WORD_LENGTH]='\0'; which is outside unsigned char (*output)[MAX_WORD_LENGTH].  if(temp_len <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH){ --> if(temp_len < MAX_WORD_LENGTH){.  Functionality first, performance later.

@Someprogrammerdude NVME SSD's have some parallel access capabilities.

Any reason why you are not using the C intrinsic function fgets() or getline() to read your file line by line instead of char by char? It has many chances to be more efficient, even without parallelizing it.

@PierU
Trust me, it's far more efficient with sys calls and mmap rather than fgets and fopen. Surely, your solution is easier, but my goal is to maximize the efficiency, In fact, I initially wrote this code with fopen and fgets and this solution speed up 2x the time of the previous version, I'm asking if it's possible to use openMp in my case to speed up even more.

I tried your code after creating an input file of 10^6 lines with words between 1 and 55 characters. And I compared to a version using getline(). The file is on a low-end SSD. When the file is already in cache, your code is 30% faster (0.09 sec. vs 0.13 s), but when the file is not in cache, your code is more than 2x slower (0.33 sec. vs 0.15 sec.).

I tried your code after creating an input file of 10^6 lines with words between 1 and 55 characters. And I compared to a version using using fopen and getline(), without any mmap. The file is on a low-end SSD. When the file is already in cache, your code is 30% faster (0.09 sec. vs 0.13 s), but when the file is not in cache, your code is more than 2x slower (0.33 sec. vs 0.15 sec.).
With the following code using OpenMP I get about a 30% speed-up (with 4 threads) when the file is in cache. When the file is not in cache there's no significant speed up.
Disclaimer: I didn't check the correctness of the results!
 int file_read_omp(const char *filename, unsigned char (*output)[MAX_WORD_LENGTH]) {
        int fd = open(filename , O_RDONLY);
        if ( fd < 0 ){
            printf("Errore nella lettura del file\n");
            perror("fd < 0");
            exit(1);
        }
        // dimensione  file in byte
        off_t file_size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

        // Mappiamo il file in memoria
        char *file_data = (char *) mmap(NULL, file_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
        if (file_data == MAP_FAILED) {
            perror("Errore nella mappatura del file");
            close(fd);
            exit(1);
        }

        close(fd);

        int num_words = 0;
        int nt;
        #pragma omp parallel
        #pragma omp single
        nt = omp_get_num_threads();
        
        size_t istart[nt+1];
        istart[nt] = file_size;
        int iwstart[nt];
        iwstart[0] = 0;
        #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:num_words)
        {
            int it = omp_get_thread_num();
            istart[it] = (file_size*it)/nt;
            if (it > 0) {
                while (file_data[istart[it]-1] != '\n') istart[it]++;
            }
            
            #pragma omp barrier    
            
            unsigned char* output_local = malloc(MAX_WORDS*MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
            
            int temp_len=0, i=istart[it];
            char tempChar;
            while ( i < istart[it+1] && num_words < MAX_WORDS ){
                tempChar = file_data[i];
                if(tempChar=='\n'){
                    if(temp_len <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH){
                        if(temp_len > 0){
                            output_local[num_words*MAX_WORD_LENGTH+temp_len]='\0';
                            temp_len = 0;
                            num_words++;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("Parola troppo grande");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }
                else if(tempChar!='\r'){
                    output_local[num_words*MAX_WORD_LENGTH+temp_len]=tempChar;
                    temp_len++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            
            iwstart[it] = 0;
            #pragma omp barrier    
            
            #pragma omp critical    
            for (int j=it+1; j<nt; j++) iwstart[j] += num_words;
            
            #pragma omp barrier    
            
            for (int iw=0; iw<num_words; iw++) {
                strcpy(output[iwstart[it]+iw],output_local+iw*MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
            }
            free(output_local);
        }
            
        //rilascio la memoria su cui era inserito il file
        munmap(file_data, file_size);
        
        return num_words;

    }


It works, thank you so much!!

I wrote a blog post about this problem a few years ago. Processing a File with OpenMP®.
My conclusion is that you're unlikely to gain performance by attempting to parallelize the read operations.
